# Не подключаются статические ресурсы в spring-webmvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Есть несколько папок со статическими ресурсами сайта:

```java
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/root/", "/verification_pages/");
}
```

Содержимое папок к сайту отлично подключается, **НО!** кроме страниц `html`! А верификационные страницы `Яндекс`, `Google` и пр. именно такие и есть.

*Что делать?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как выяснилось: `spring` на самом деле подключал ВСЁ содержимое вышеуказанных папок, включая страницы `html`, **НО!** поскольку для страниц, расположенных в корне у меня был настроен отдельный метод - приоритет был у него, а статическим ресурсам ничего не доставалось.

**Выход:**

Параметр [`path`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#path--) аннотации [`@RequestMapping`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) поддерживает *"Ant-style path patterns"*. В моем случае для страниц в корне сайта мэппинг был такой:

```java
@RequestMapping("/{name}.html")
```

добавил к нему паттерн, не учитывающий цифры в имени:

```java
@RequestMapping("/{name:\\D+}.html")
```

---

См. [Learning Ant path style](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22636142/8280225)